# Construct a sequence.

Tags: probability-distributions

We know that, if a sequence $\{\xi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset [0,1)$ is equidistributed, then it must be dense in $[0,1)$.

My problem is, how to construct a sequence $\{\xi_n\}$ that is dense but not equidistributed?

Comment: Is this a question in distribution theory?

Comment: It looks more like [probability-distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-distributions). I changed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{\alpha_n\}_1^\infty \subset [0, \frac12)$ and $\{\beta_n\}_1^\infty \subset [\frac12, 1)$ be equidistributed on their respective sets. Then let
$$
\xi_1=\alpha_1,\ \xi_2=\beta_1,\ \xi_3=\beta_2,\\
\xi_4=\alpha_2,\ \xi_5=\beta_3,\ \xi_6=\beta_4,\\
\xi_7=\alpha_3,\ \xi_8=\beta_5,\ \xi_9=\beta_6,\\
\ldots$$
This isn't equidistributed on $[0, 1),$ is it?